# Execute R script from PHP with Apache Server

Tags: php, r, apache

I want to execute a R script (named script.R) within PHP code with an Apache Web Server.
Here is my R code : I install packages then import data then I can proceed a classification tree on the data:

```
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library(rpart)
library(sqldf)
library(survival)
library(randomForest)
library(rpart.plot)

data=read.table(file = "t.txt",header = T,sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = T)

input=read.table(file = "file.txt",header = T,sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = T)

tree=rpart(sat~.,data,method="class")


png("tree.png", width=1000, height=800, antialias="cleartype")
plot(tree, uniform=TRUE,
     main="Classification Tree")
text(tree, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=0.8)

dev.off()
```

My php script must execute this R script. They are placed in "C:\Apache24\htdocs" with "file.txt" and "t.txt"

So my php file consists in :

```
<?php
exec("Rscript script.R", $results);
print_r($results);
?>
```

But I get "Array()"

Any idea?

Comment: Try using `passthru()` to get all of the output. `exec()` only returns the last line: http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: Same results ! It get return "1". I suppose that means that the execution worked but i dont have the plot ("tree.png") .
Maybe R is not installed on the server. How could I check if it is?

Answer (score 1):

Install required `R` packages in system-wide location. On my machine this requires:

```
$ sudo R
> install.packages("Rpkg", lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/")
```

**Explanation**:

I see you have installed couple of `R` packages. And I'm guessing that you have installed them in default location i.e. user home directory.

So if you try to execute your `R` script from command-line, something like:

```
$ php foo.php
```

You'll see that the script gets executed successfully (assuming rest of the code is bug free) and the `script.R` gets called as expected.

But this will fail when you try to execute `php` from apache. The reason is that since you have installed `R` packages in home directory they are inaccessible to `www-data`, the user which executes php under apache.